# Xamarin AndroidGameView : can't figure out why VertexShader / FragmentShader does not compile

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, shader

I'm trying to work with shaders with this Xamarin Sample (I have already work a bit on shaders with SFML):
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/GLTriangle20/

I'm trying to make a new project and re-create a AndroidGameView class (such as PaintingView in this sample).

But I can't compile my VertexShader and my Fragment shader.

What I have done so far :

- My FrameBuffer is created.
- OnLoad base function has been called.
- I created a string where my shaders are stored before compilation (same shaders in the sample)
- Create a shader with GL.CreateShader => result is not 0
- Store my sourceCode in the vertex shader handle with GL.ShaderSource
- Try to compile with GL.CompileShader => GL.GetShader indicates that it did not compile.

here is the vertex shader string :

```
string vertexShaderSrc = "attribute vec4 vPosition;    \n" +
                              "void main()                  \n" +
                              "{                            \n" +
                              "   gl_Position = vPosition;  \n" +
                              "}                            \n";
```

and here is the loading function called after declaration of the string, where "type = ShaderType.VertexShader" and "source = vertexShaderSrc" :

```
int LoadShader(ShaderType type, string source)
        {
            int shader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);


                if (shader == 0)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to create shader");

                int[] length = { 0 };

                GL.ShaderSource(shader, 1, new string[] { source }, (int[])null);
                GL.CompileShader(shader);

                int[] compiled = { 0 } ;
                GL.GetShader(shader, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, compiled);
                if (compiled[0] == 0)
                {
                    length[0] = 0;
                    GL.GetShader(shader, ShaderParameter.InfoLogLength, length);
                    if (length[0] > 0)
                    {
                        var log = new StringBuilder(length[0]);
                        GL.GetShaderInfoLog(shader, length[0], length, log);
                        Log.Debug("GL2", "Couldn't compile shader: " + log.ToString());
                    }

                    GL.DeleteShader(shader);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to compile shader of type : " + type.ToString());
                }

            return shader;
        }
```

What step do I miss ? Is there a particular setting to do in Xamarin ? I don't think that the problem is related to the shader itself because it's the same in the sample.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

The trick was quite simple :

Don"t forget to add the following line in CreateFrameBuffer :

```
ContextRenderingApi = GLVersion.ES2;
```

Problem solved.